# Combine JavaScript date object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on app and I want to show 3 columns

```
date, min and zone
```

I am getting an array of objects

```
[
{date: 2022-12-28T07:37:16.859Z, min: 2, zone: zone A},
{date: 2022-12-28T07:38:13.859Z, min: 1, zone: zone B},
{date: 2022-12-28T07:36:15.859Z, min: 3, zone: zone C},
{date: 2022-12-31T07:37:16.859Z, min: 2, zone: zone E}
{date: 2022-12-25T07:37:16.859Z, min: 4, zone: zone D}
]
```

I want to cover condition as below:

1. If date is repeating then it should be repeated only once.
2. min with same date should be addition like (2+1+3=6)
3. zone with same date should be concat like (Zone A, Zone B, Zone C)

and want result like below:

```
   [
    {date: 2022-12-28T07:37:16.859Z, min: 6, zone: zone A, zone B, zone C},
    {date: 2022-12-31T07:37:16.859Z, min: 2, zone: zone E}
    {date: 2022-12-25T07:37:16.859Z, min: 4, zone: zone D}
    ]
```

any help is apricated.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out elements with a duplicate date, and when you remove them add/concat the min/zone values to the remaining object's respective values.

[How to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to format date according to manage condition in code

```js
a = [
  {date: "2022-12-28", min: 2, zone: "zone A"},
  {date: "2022-12-28", min: 1, zone: "zone B"},
  {date: "2022-12-28", min: 3, zone: "zone C"},
  {date: "2022-12-31", min: 2, zone: "zone E"},
  {date: "2022-12-25", min: 4, zone: "zone D"}
]

let h = []
a.forEach(item => {
    let data = h.find(e => e.date == item.date);
    if(data){
        data.min = data.min + item.min;
        data.zone = data.zone + ", " + item.zone;
        let index = h.findIndex(e => e.date == item.date);
        h[index] = data
    }else
        h.push(item)
})
console.log(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result requires grouped by `date` (with Date only).

You can work with `.reduce()` to group the data by `date`.

1. When there is no element with `date` found in the group, you need to create an object with `k` and `v`. Next push it into the accumulator (`acc`) array.
2. When there is an element with `date` match in the existing group, you need to update the existing element in the `acc` array for the `min` and `zone`.

Lastly, you need to grab all the `v` values from the `groupedDate` array.

```
let input = [
    { date: "2022-12-28T07:37:16.859Z", min: 2, zone: "zone A" },
    { date: "2022-12-28T07:38:13.859Z", min: 1, zone: "zone B" },
    { date: "2022-12-28T07:36:15.859Z", min: 3, zone: "zone C" },
    { date: "2022-12-31T07:37:16.859Z", min: 2, zone: "zone E" },
    { date: "2022-12-25T07:37:16.859Z", min: 4, zone: "zone D" }
];

let groupedDate = input.reduce(
    (acc: { k: string, v: { date: string; min: number; zone: string[] } }[], 
    cur: { date: string, min: number, zone: string }) => {

    let date = new Date(cur.date);
    let dateString = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;

    let index = acc.findIndex(x => x.k == dateString);
    if (index > -1) {
        acc[index].v.min += cur.min;
        acc[index].v.zone.push(cur.zone);
    } else {
        acc.push({
            k: dateString,
            v: { date: cur.date, min: cur.min, zone: [cur.zone] }
        });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

let result = groupedDate.map(x => x.v);
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgDgV0gXggbQFAWxA3hAEwEMwQAuCAIgCYAGa6gWgEYnqAOAFVoHYyBmPswBsAOnYBWAJwAtSgBoIAW1gVqigF4B7GOSrbdEAIKUIAX3lYc+YqQo16TVow7c+-dmWb9x0uYpUYCmZNHT1KAxAIACFTCytsGxJwugYWNi5eAWEvCV9ZBWVVCH5Q3XtIiABhOMscPEJk+1SnJn5mNwEhMUkCgOL1CEiKsIgAUVqEhtsUx3SXCU7BLx6-QsCKABYy8MqAETiMAF0AbgwMUEgAcwAnLQQ4EAI95IhUWEQwURunhABjEAACimgKIfz+FHwAGsKABnMA3WBXRQAN0hjTsEHhiJgVxORSCEBgCCUACMQDd8cMsQikWgjuZzPTFFM-ggbuiZnDabj+oTiWSKTtuTiruYAJRvAB8eHO9UuGKiqF0AHcIC9SIC2TdRDNxWd5eBFQBlHli1AAAwAJLgZqIruAAGIIYDAACaICIN0B4rMjBtdodYAAsjowAALH0QADUEGYfoDyXt4A1QN9FrOUwVsAIIAAHm8IGC-qIAGY5gCSMFzecBBeQMrzoihb1QM1Nov1UygpYggJz+YgMpYktwU3qxbQA7zR1EKNEgRjqG1C9gBvqOEn09n88iokQsMjK8iXfqZggIGAsKiY43m-B+4Qh8Bt7vG5hJrNdTf9TR0yaEArjMfIUCugTCugx5hAyZjjjgZinvBco4D8YDsjARbgmcFjoEcXYXEaPywi6KAQLc9yPM8SZKEQcB1tKEBNiiXZ-DosJaKAojAFoVyAkRJH6kAA)

Answer (score -2):

you can use the Array.map() method to create a new array of objects that combine a JavaScript Date object with other properties.

```
let dateArray = [new Date(), new Date(), new Date()];

let dataArray = dateArray.map(date => {
  return {
    date: date,
    value: Math.random()
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).